# Jquery find parent element looking for the first element with specific data

Tags: jquery

I want to retrieve `_tagName_`, `_classname_` and data info (`data-droprow="7"`, in this case) of the parent of the first element of class `".item assigned"` that has `data-rowtm="1"`.

```
<table class="otable">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="batt" data-rowbatt="1">
            <td class="drop droppable" data-droprow="3"></td>
            <td class="drop droppable" data-droprow="4"></td>
            <td class="drop droppable" data-droprow="5"></td>
            <td class="drop droppable" data-droprow="6"></td>
            <td class="drop droppable" data-droprow="7">
                <div class="item assigned" data-rowtm="1" data-endtm="13" data-starttm="7"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="drop droppable" data-droprow="8"></td>
            <td class="drop droppable" data-droprow="9">
        </tr>          
    </tbody>
</table>
```

something similar to :

```
var $div = $(".drop droppable").find("[data-rowtm='" + variable + "']");
```

Comment: Did you checked that? https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: `variable` contains correctly the number 1, but console.log() returns 'undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `.filter()` the `td` elements:

```js
var td = $('.otable .drop.droppable').filter(function(){
   return $(this).find('.item.assigned').length !== 0;
});

console.log('tag ::::->', td.prop('tagName'))
console.log('data-droprow ::::->', td.data('droprow'))
console.log('class ::::->', td.attr('class'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="otable" width='500' border='1'>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="batt" data-rowbatt="1">
      <td class="drop droppable" data-droprow="3"></td>
      <td class="drop droppable" data-droprow="4"></td>
      <td class="drop droppable" data-droprow="5"></td>
      <td class="drop droppable" data-droprow="6"></td>
      <td class="drop droppable" data-droprow="7">
        <div class="item assigned" data-rowtm="1" data-endtm="13" data-starttm="7">dd7</div>
      </td>
      <td class="drop droppable" data-droprow="8"></td>
      <td class="drop droppable" data-droprow="9">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is almost correct, using [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent) you can achieve you can select the parent of the element containing the given data. Demo https://jsfiddle.net/4o3m6euv/1/

```
var variable=1;//Or whatever you search for...
var $div = $(".drop.droppable [data-rowtm='" + variable + "']").parent();
alert($div.data('droprow'));//Gives '7'
alert($div.prop('class'));//Gives 'drop droppable'
alert($div.prop('tagName'));//Gives 'TD'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
var $div = $(".drop droppable").find("[data-rowtm='" + variable + "']");
```

...is really close, you just want a `.` instead of space after `.drop`:

```
var $div = $(".drop.droppable").find("[data-rowtm='" + variable + "']");
// ----------------^
```

Alternately, all in one:

```
var $div = $(".drop.droppable [data-rowtm='" + variable + "']");
```

Comment: something more interesting is happening,`console.log($div.html())` returns the HTML output, but `console.log($div.data())` returns [object Object]

Comment: @MorRob: It would do (though many consoles are more informative than that). If you don't pass any arguments to jQuery's `data` function, it returns an object with properties for all the data items stored on the element. (Note: Be sure to read up on [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data), it's one of the most misunderstood jQuery functions in the entire API.)